# How should I add new files when I already have multiple branches

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging

We have recently started using GIT and it has worked out well, but we sometimes hits bumps that we don't know how to best solve.

Right now we have multiple branches. master, develop and lots of feature branches (one or more per developer).

Now we want to add a directory with some script-files, and these files are needed by all developers (immediately).

How should we best perform this? I was thinking maybe adding a new branch (from develop), add the files there and then let everyone else merge from it?

Or is there a better, cleaner, more git'ish way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it to your central branch (normally `dev` or `develop`) and ask everyone to `git merge` or `git rebase` from it, which they are normally meant to be doing regularly anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Either record the ancestry explicitly by making the new commit at the merge base of all the branches then `git merge --no-ff`ing that, or make the new commit anyplace and cherry-pick it from everywhere else. There's [a very widely-used branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) that uses the branch-and-merge-no-ff method.